# Vertically translated depreciation curve: Update the exponential regression coefficient

Tags: regression, data-transformation, exponential-distribution, curves, projection

I have an **exponential regression equation** that I use to **predict the condition of roads**.

The equation can be found on **page 53** of the original master's thesis: [Development of a Flexible Framework for Deterioration Modelling in Infrastructure Asset Management](https://tspace.library.utoronto.ca/bitstream/1807/33410/1/Ens_Abra_M_201211_MASc_thesis.pdf)

From page 53:

[image]

The equation has some IF statements which deal with specific roads-related scenarios. For the purpose of this question, I'll boil it down to it's simplest form:

> `condition = 21 - EXP(0.072*age)`

---

### Question:

The equation was developed for my organization back in **2012**. At that time, the roads had only been inspected once. Now, fast-forward to **2017**, and we have **a lot more data to work with**.

So, I think it would be wise to update the equation. If we were able to redo the analysis with the new data, I suspect we'd be able to predict the future condition of roads more accurately.

However, as non-stats guy, I'm finding this to be rather difficult.

**How can I update the coefficient in the exponential regression equation?**

---

Related:

[Tune an exponential regression estimate using calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4352984/tune-an-exponential-regression-estimate-using-calculus)

Comment: Do you need it to be of the form $y=a+be^{cx}$ necessarily? Is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to follow the same curve form, you set the y-intercept to 21 like the original author did. Then, the equation you need to estimate is
$$y=21-e^{ax},$$

which is equivalent to

$$21-y=e^{ax}.$$

If you take logarithms both sides (you can do it because $y<21$), then
$$log(21-y)=ax.$$

Renaming $log(21-y)=z$, this is of the form
$$z=ax,$$

which is a linear regression with no intercept that can be estimated with many standard software packages.

For the lower bound you would, instead of the 21, use the 21-1.282-8.277 (the worst-case condition in the conditionals) as a y-intercept, and apply the same estimation method.

Comment: So at age 0, $e^{ax}=e^0=1$, and we want to find an intercept such that at age $x=0$ we have $y=20$. If the intercept was $20$, then, at age 0, $y=20-e^{0}=20-1=19$, which is not the state of new roads.

Comment: A more general approach to estimate the y-intercept, if it is not as explicitly determined by the context as in this case, would be to compute the average of the $y$ conditional on $x=0$ (so the average condition for all roads of age=0 but only those) and add 1 for the same reason we add 1 to make the 20-score be an intercept of 21. Or, if you want upper-lower bounds like in the example, the average for the best-case roads at $x=0$, and of the worst-case roads at $x=0$ will give you two the two intercepts.